# Can any compact subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ be written as a suitable YFS attractor?

Tags: fractals, iterated-function-system

I'm wondering. Can any compact subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ be written as a suitable IFS attractor?

Can someone explain? Thank you for visiting my question.

Comment: A circle is certainly not self-similar. On the other hand, the [Collage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage_theorem) guarantees that you can construct an IFS whose attractor is as close you would like to any given set.

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is no; they prove it not just for the plane, but for any uncountable Polish space.  I haven't read the paper, so I'm not sure EXACTLY where the result is:

http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol38/vol38pp797-804.pdf

This paper discusses the result, as well as generalizations of the question to infinite IFS's:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X1931008X

There are some positive results; in the paper above, they prove it for certain sets containing clopen copies of the Cantor Set.  It's also known for polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^n$.